# Java GroupLayout positioning

Tags: java, jframe, grouplayout

I am having complications trying to setup my GroupLayout. I am trying to go off a tutorial from oracle's website but for the life of me cannot figure it out.  Below is my current layout design followed by the code, not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image]

```
GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(layout);

        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(launchButton)
                .addComponent(modeComboBox)
                .addComponent(difficultyComboBox)
                .addComponent(mapComboBox)
                .addComponent(startButton)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))    
        );

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(launchButton)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                            .addComponent(modeComboBox)
                            .addComponent(difficultyComboBox)
                            .addComponent(mapComboBox)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                            .addComponent(startButton))
        );
```

My Goal is to have it end up looking something like the picture below...

[image]

Comment: GroupLayout is designed for use by an automated layout tool, like in the NetBeans IDE.  It's pretty hard to use on its own.  Could you lay this out with NetBeans?

Comment: I dont see why I couldnt, I have just always used eclipse.

Comment: If Eclipse has a layout / builder tool, that's fine too.  It's just that layouts like this can be tricky to do by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started up NetBeans and laid out something like your picture showed.  Try this and see if it's what you're looking for.

```
package quicktest;

public class ChaosLayout extends javax.swing.JPanel {

   /**
    * Creates new form ChaosLayout
    */
   public ChaosLayout() {
      initComponents();
   }

   /**
    * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
    * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
    * regenerated by the Form Editor.
    */
   @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
   private void initComponents() {

      jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
      jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
      jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
      jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
      jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

      jButton1.setText("jButton1");

      jButton2.setText("jButton2");

      jButton3.setText("jButton3");

      jButton4.setText("jButton4");

      jButton5.setText("jButton5");

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
      this.setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(55, 55, 55)
            .addComponent(jButton3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
               .addComponent(jButton1)
               .addComponent(jButton2)
               .addComponent(jButton5))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton4)
            .addContainerGap(84, Short.MAX_VALUE))
      );
      layout.setVerticalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(jButton2)
               .addComponent(jButton3)
               .addComponent(jButton4))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 180, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton5)
            .addContainerGap())
      );
   }// </editor-fold>                        


   // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
   // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Same layout, with sensible variable names, and I added a constraint to make the buttons all the same width, which I thought looked a little better.

```
package quicktest;

public class ChaosLayout extends javax.swing.JPanel {

   /**
    * Creates new form ChaosLayout
    */
   public ChaosLayout() {
      initComponents();
   }

   /**
    * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
    * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
    * regenerated by the Form Editor.
    */
   @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
   private void initComponents() {

      launch = new javax.swing.JButton();
      chaos = new javax.swing.JButton();
      trials = new javax.swing.JButton();
      map = new javax.swing.JButton();
      start = new javax.swing.JButton();

      launch.setText("Launch");

      chaos.setText("Chaos");

      trials.setText("Trials");

      map.setText("Map");

      start.setText("Start");

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
      this.setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(55, 55, 55)
            .addComponent(trials)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
               .addComponent(launch)
               .addComponent(chaos)
               .addComponent(start))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(map)
            .addContainerGap(99, Short.MAX_VALUE))
      );

      layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {chaos, launch, map, start, trials});

      layout.setVerticalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(launch)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(chaos)
               .addComponent(trials)
               .addComponent(map))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 180, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(start)
            .addContainerGap())
      );
   }// </editor-fold>                        


   // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
   private javax.swing.JButton chaos;
   private javax.swing.JButton launch;
   private javax.swing.JButton map;
   private javax.swing.JButton start;
   private javax.swing.JButton trials;
   // End of variables declaration                   
}
```